# How to use ReactJS in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I am looking for a way to integrate it in Laravel. Is there any way that I can use React components within laravel views or it should be done only by using API as separate projects.

Comment: Depend on what you need. Do you want to make an SPA or Server side rendering?

Comment: I needed a Javascript library to load some views in laravel but I found out that Vuejs is a better solution

Comment: https://youtu.be/k-xCNQGxUn0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Laravel to provide the base view, but then after that all the views would be handled by React.Then Use Laravel as API and React as front-end. Also have a look at [this blog](https://tighten.co/blog/adding-react-components-to-a-laravel-app/)

Comment: Put this as comment

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to put it as comment. I wish to enter it as a comment, but couldn't.

Comment: Thank you the link it was very useful. It gave me the idea to use VueJs instead of React and it was everything I needed

Answer (score 0):

have a page as a root for react and do not forget to add every react page in web.php

`Route::view('/courselist', 'app');`

all your folders inside src should be copied into resources/js/react. then implement this in webpack.mix.js:

`.js('resources/js/react', 'public/js/reactJs').react()`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66545875/13266927

Answer (score 0):

To can use React Js with Laravel By creating Api's in laravel and later on integrating those APIs in react js project using **Axios()** or **fetch()** in react js. Steps to do it as follows:

1. **Create Database** in MySQL Database let's say using the name as **"employees"**
2. Install laravel, Create a new project in laravel and create a controller using the command
   `php artisan make:controller EmployeeController`
3. Create Route in routes folder and inside it in api.php import controller using
   `use App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController;`
   and then Create a route using:
   `Route::post('/employee',[EmployeeController::class,'employee']);`
4. Create a function in EmployeeController named **employee**
   and controller will be look like this as below:

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Employee;

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    function employee(Request $req){
        $employee = new Employee;
        $employee -> TName=$req->input("TName");
        $employee -> TID=$req->input("TID");
        $employee -> Cnic=$req->input("Cnic");
        $employee -> Email=$req->input("Email");
        $employee -> Designation=$req->input("Designation");
        $employee -> DId=$req->input("DId");
        $employee -> Gender=$req->input("Gender");
        $employee -> Address=$req->input("Address");
        $employee -> PhNumber=$req->input("PhNumber");
        $employee -> Skill=$req->input("Skill");
        $employee->save();
        return $employee;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps=false;
}
```

5. After this test API http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee which was declared in api.php **/employee** in postman tool then later us this in react js project as below:

```
// import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
// import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import "./assignsubjectteacher.css";
// import Header from "./Header.js";

function Assignsubjectteacher() {
  const [TName, setTName] = useState("");
  const [TID, setTID] = useState("");
  const [Cnic, setCnic] = useState("");
  const [Email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [Designation, setDesignation] = useState("");
  const [DId, setDId] = useState("");
  const [Gender, setGender] = useState("");
  const [Address, setAddress] = useState("");
  const [PhNumber, setPhNumber] = useState("");
  // const [IsHOD, setIsHOD] = useState("");
  const [Skill, setSkill] = useState("");

  async function assignsubjectteacher() {
    // console.warn(name, department);

    let item = {
      TName,
      TID,
      Cnic,
      Email,
      Designation,
      DId,
      Gender,
      Address,
      PhNumber,
      // IsHOD,
      Skill,
    };
    // console.log(item);
    let result = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });
    result = await result.json();
    localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(result));
    console.warn(result);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-sm-8 offset-sm-3">
        <div className="mt-10 col-sm-9 center">
          <br />
          <br />
          <h2>Add Faculty</h2>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Teacher's Name"
            className="col-sm-12 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setTName(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Teacher's ID"
            className="col-sm-4 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setTID(e.target.value)}
          />

          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter CNIC"
            className="col-sm-4 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setCnic(e.target.value)}
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            className="col-sm-4 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Designation"
            className="col-sm-4 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setDesignation(e.target.value)}
          />

          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter DId"
            className="col-sm-4 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setDId(e.target.value)}
          />

          <select
            placeholder="Select Gender"
            className="col-sm-4 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setGender(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option>Select Gender</option>
            <option>Male</option>
            <option>Female</option>
          </select>
          <br />

          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Address"
            className="form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="tel"
            placeholder="Phone"
            className="col-sm-6 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setPhNumber(e.target.value)}
            pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Skill"
            className="col-sm-6 form-control"
            onChange={(e) => setSkill(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          {/* <label for="IsHOD">IsHOD</label> */}
          {/* <input
            id="IsHOD"
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={(e) => setIsHOD(e.target.value)}
          /> */}
          <br />
          <br />
          <button onClick={assignsubjectteacher} className="btn btn-danger">
            Add
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default Assignsubjectteacher;
```